# Nameless properties

Tags: javascript, typescript

I was wondering if there was a nameless property feature in typescript, or if it can be achieved. For example I have a T class object.

```
class T {
    Key:any; 
    Value:any; 
}
```

I can another function that takes an array of T objects, and parses them into a FormData object. There is not pattern, and thus whenever i call the function have have to type out Key and Value into every object

```
let array = [
                {Key:"id",Value:  "2"}, 
                {Key:"email",Value:  "generic"}, 
                {Key:"type",Value:"Food"}, 
                {Key:"name",Value: "someName"} 
                .......
];
```

It would look a lot cleaner and be more efficient if I could just type out two string values like so

```
let array = [
                {"id","2"}, 
                {"email","generic"}, 
                {"type","Food"}, 
                {"name","someName"} 
                .......
];
```

Can this be achieved in typescript/javascript, if so how?

Comment: You could use `.map()` to add the property names.

Comment: It's not a typescript answer, but the `map` array function lets you transform each element of an array into something else. You could take your vanilla array as input and output an array of key/value pair objects.

Comment: Yeah typescript/javascript doesn’t matter. link please?

Comment: I checkout Maps, but i would still have to do something like this 
var x: Map<any, any> = new Map<any, any>();
x.set("id", "2");

Comment: It would be helpful to see your function and how you're getting your array input data. I wasn't talking about a Map object, but rather [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). The second example is the reverse of what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) and [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to achieve this.

```
let content = [
    ["id","2"], 
    ["email","generic"], 
    ["type","Food"], 
    ["name","someName"] 
]; 

let finalArray = content.map(([Key, Value]) => ({Key, Value}));
```

The advantage of using a tuple type here is that if your content specification has less than two elements in a row it will cause a compile error.

Note that in the `.map` call I'm using typescript's [destructuring](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/destructuring.html) and field punning features.

Comment: I tried to include documentation links for everything but I can't seem to find documentation for punning anywhere o_O. Maybe I should write some... Anyway, it compiles just fine.